# Issue with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this is my htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) url.php?p=$1 [NC]
```

Im trying to redirect like this: mysite.com/sometext to mysite.com/url.php?p=sometext

But with that file the browser gives me always an error; *Internal Server Error, The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding some conditions to keep mod_rewrite from looping internally forever:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/url.php
```

Or:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Right before the `RewriteRule`

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. The "L" ensures that it will be last rewrite rule, which should prevent the loop.

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://mysite.com/url.php?p=$1 [NC,R,L]

This one might work too (will need to try it out)

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ url.php?p=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: The leading slash is stripped off when matching by apache when a RewriteRule is in .htaccess